# Cash basis salary for uk visa

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, pakistan

I changed job from private limited company to sole trader and they are paying in cash ? 
Can a cash basis payslips bhe approved for UK visitor visa ?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Visa applicants for the UK usually have to prove their sources of income.

Answer (score 1):

The visa officers who process your application at the UK High Commission will be well aware that many people in Pakistan are paid in cash and will happily accept cash basis payslips as evidence of income. A statement from your employer showing your salary, role and start date is also acceptable.

Keep in mind that the visa officers will be interested not only in your income but in your full financial circumstances. You may wish to read the UK's official [Guide to supporting documents: visiting the UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk) to see what other documents you may wish to submit to improve your visa application. While no document is strictly required other than your passport, if not enough information is provided to allow the visa officer to understand your financial situation, your visa will be refused. Therefore, you should also [include bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/3221) if you have a bank account, and documentation of all deposits made into the account(s). For instance, if your previous job paid you by bank transfer, then you should include payslips for those transfers.